# Flink Processing Time Characteristic Context Returning timestamp

Tags: apache-flink, pyflink

## Summary

When configuring flink to use processing time I would expect the context.timestamp() to return null in a keyed processing function. When doing testing it seems to return the ingestion timestamp from the source kafka topic.

## Details

I am using pyflink 1.16.1 with the Datastream environment.
I configure the application to use processing time as follows.

```py
env.set_stream_time_characteristic(TimeCharacteristic.ProcessingTime)
```

I also configure watermarking on the source as follows:

```py
properties = get_kafka_properties(args) # Security config
kafka_source = KafkaSource.builder()\
        .set_properties(properties)\
        .set_topics(topic)\
        .set_starting_offsets(KafkaOffsetsInitializer.earliest())\
        .set_value_only_deserializer(SimpleStringSchema())\
        .build()
source = env.from_source(
        source=kafka_source,
        watermark_strategy=WatermarkStrategy.no_watermarks()
        source_name="kafka_source")
```

When I use this simple test processing function I see that the time the message arrived in the kafka queue is used whereas I expected null to be returned.

```py
class TestProcessFunction(KeyedProcessFunction):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def process_element(self, value, ctx: 'KeyedProcessFunction.Context'):
        yield ctx.timestamp()
```

It makes me wonder if processing time is indeed being used or if there is a mistake in my configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't working as expected because the use of `set_stream_time_characteristic` was deprecated within Flink 1.12 [per the release notes](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/release-notes/flink-1.12/#flip-134-batch-execution-for-the-datastream-api):

> Deprecate StreamExecutionEnvironment.setStreamTimeCharacteristic() and TimeCharacteristic

As well as:

> In Flink 1.12 the default stream time characteristic has been changed to EventTime, thus you don’t need to call this method for enabling event-time support anymore. Explicitly using processing-time windows and timers works in event-time mode. If you need to disable watermarks, please use ExecutionConfig.setAutoWatermarkInterval(long). If you are using IngestionTime, please manually set an appropriate WatermarkStrategy. If you are using generic “time window” operations (for example KeyedStream.timeWindow()) that change behaviour based on the time characteristic, please use equivalent operations that explicitly specify processing time or event time.

This may explain why you are seeing the behavior that you are currently experiencing. The use of `WatermarkStrategy.no_watermarks()` should be sufficient for your case. You may also consider looking at the available [`TimerService`](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/TimerService.html) that is exposed by your context to access other timing-related information as needed (e.g. current processing time, current watermarks, etc.):

```
def process_element(self, value, ctx: 'KeyedProcessFunction.Context'):
    # The timer service can expose some additional timing info based on your use-case 
    yield ctx.timer_service().current_processing_time()
```